# Having trouble with pointers and 2D arrays

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

*NOTE: This code cannot use array indices [ ] [ ]. Only pointers can be used. [ ] [ ] are okay to use only for array declaration.*

I am comparing an array of same size as of array image called **copyArray** and array **image** itself. First I initialize the **copyArray** with all 0s using pointers which I checked using printf and works correctly.

function **colorPtr** simply checks for all the 1s in array image and calls function **distinctCountPointer**.
function **distinctCountPointer** checks for all 1s that are connected(from up, down, left, right or diagonal) to each other and groups them by giving a **unique integer**. (See output(that should be) for a clear idea).

I was able to do this code without using pointers, but I'm having trouble using pointers. Any help would be appreciated.

```
void colorPtr(int* image){
    int copyArray[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE];
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<IMAGE_SIZE; i++)
        for(j=0; j<IMAGE_SIZE; j++){
            *(*(copyArray + i) + j) = 0;
            //printf("%d ", *(*(copyArray +i) + j));
        }

    // going to all adjacent positions and running distinctCount function 
    int counter = 1;
    for(i=0;i<IMAGE_SIZE;i++){
        for(j=0;j<IMAGE_SIZE;j++){
            if(*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)==0 && *(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)!=0){ //error line
                distinctCountPointer(image, i, j, copyArray, counter);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

function **colorPtr** then calls **distinctCountPointer**. This function simply gives 1s that are connected to each other from up, down, left, right and diagonals with a unique number.

```
void distinctCountPointer(int * image, int i, int j, int * copyArray, int counter){  
    *(copyArray + i*10 + j) = 1;
    *(image + i*10 + j) = counter;

    int new_i, new_j;
    for(new_i =-1;new_i <2;new_i ++){
        for(new_j = -1;new_j < 2; new_j++){
            if(new_i  != 0 || new_j != 0){
                if(checkIndex(i+new_i, j+new_j)){
                    if(if(*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)==0 && *(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)!=0){
                        distinctCountPointer(image, i+new_i , j+new_j, copyArray, counter);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
void printImgArray(int array[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE])
{
  
    printf("------ Image Contents -------\n");
    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<IMAGE_SIZE; i++)
    {
    for (j=0; j<IMAGE_SIZE; j++)
        printf("%02d, ",array[i][j]);
    printf("\n");
    }
    printf("-----------------------------\n");
}
```

```
int checkIndex(int i, int j){
    return i >= 0 && j>=0 && i< IMAGE_SIZE && j< IMAGE_SIZE;
}
```

Here is my **main**.

```
int main(){
int cellImg_[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE]={{0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},\
                       {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1},\
                       {1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},\
                       {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},\
                       {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},\
                       {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},\
                       {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},\
                       {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},\
                       {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
                       {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}};

    int* ptr = cellImg_;
    printImgArray(ptr);
    colorPtr(ptr);
    printImgArray(ptr);
    count=cellCountPtr(ptr);
    printf("Total number of cells in the image: %d\n",count);
}
```

Sample Input:-

```
00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 
01, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 
01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 
01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 
01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 
00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 01, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 
00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 01
```

Output (shown):-

```
00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 
01, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 
01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 01, 00, 01, 
01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 
01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 
00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 01, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 
00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 01, 01, 01
```

Output(that should be):-

```
00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 02, 00, 00, 03, 
04, 00, 01, 01, 00, 00, 02, 02, 00, 03, 
04, 00, 00, 01, 01, 00, 02, 02, 00, 03, 
04, 04, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 
04, 00, 00, 05, 05, 05, 00, 00, 05, 00, 
00, 00, 00, 00, 05, 00, 00, 05, 05, 00, 
00, 00, 06, 00, 00, 05, 00, 05, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 06, 06, 00, 00, 05, 00, 00, 00, 
00, 00, 06, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 07, 07, 
00, 06, 06, 00, 00, 00, 07, 07, 07, 07
```

Comment: Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Upvoted for a description, and particularly the desired vs. the actual output. As @anastaciu said, providing the missing code pieces would be good (printImgArray?).

Comment: Sure, I have made the necessary changes. Thanks

Comment: can you use recursion?

Comment: Yes I can. I did use it without pointers and it worked. Just not able to do the same with pointers.

Comment: In `colorPtr`, `if(*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)==0 && *(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)!=0){` should be `if(*(*(copyArray + i) + j)==0 && *(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)!=0){`, but it would be clearer to replace `*(*(copyArray + i) + j)` with `copyArray[i][j]` and to replace `*(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)` with `image[i * IMAGE_SIZE + j]`, giving `if(copyArray[i][j]==0 && image[i * IMAGE_SIZE + j]!=0){`.

Comment: What is `if(if(` in `distinctCountPointer`? And the `cellCountPtr()` function is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is using invalid coordinates when iterating over cell neighbourhood in `distinctCountPointer`. It should be:

```
@@ -16,7 +16,7 @@ void distinctCountPointer(int * image, int i, int j, int * copyArray, int counte
         for(new_j = -1;new_j < 2; new_j++){
             if(new_i  != 0 || new_j != 0){
                 if(checkIndex(i+new_i, j+new_j)){
-                    if(if(*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)==0 && *(image + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)!=0){
+                    if(*(copyArray + (i+new_i) * IMAGE_SIZE + (j+new_j))==0 && *(image + (i+new_i) * IMAGE_SIZE + (j+new_j))!=0){
                         distinctCountPointer(image, i+new_i , j+new_j, copyArray, counter);
                     }
                 }
```

Anyway, I suggest using VLA to greatly simplify the code.
It allows to replace ugly expressions like `*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)` with `copyArray[i][j]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fill(int mark, int y, int x,  int h, int w, int src[h][w], int dst[h][w]) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= w || y < 0 || y >= h || src[y][x] == 0 || dst[y][x] != 0)
        return;
    dst[y][x] = mark;
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
        for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
            fill(mark, y + i, x + j, h, w, src, dst);
}

int find_cells(int h, int w, int src[h][w], int dst[h][w]) {
    memset(dst, 0, sizeof(int[h][w]));
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j)
            if (src[i][j] == 1 && dst[i][j] == 0)
                fill(++counter, i, j, h, w, src, dst);
    return counter;
}

void print(int h, int w, int img[h][w]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
            printf("%3d", img[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}

int main(){
    enum { IMAGE_SIZE = 10 };
    int inp[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE]={
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1},
        {1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1},
        {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1},
        {0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1}
    };
    int out[IMAGE_SIZE][IMAGE_SIZE];

    print(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, inp);
    int count = find_cells(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, inp, out);
    printf("Total number of cells in the image: %d\n",count);
    print(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, out);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  1
  1  0  1  1  0  0  1  1  0  1
  1  0  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1
  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0
  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  0
  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  0
  0  0  1  1  0  0  1  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1
  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  1  1  1
Total number of cells in the image: 7
  0  0  1  1  0  0  2  0  0  3
  4  0  1  1  0  0  2  2  0  3
  4  0  0  1  1  0  2  2  0  3
  4  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  4  0  0  5  5  5  0  0  5  0
  0  0  0  0  5  0  0  5  5  0
  0  0  6  0  0  5  0  5  0  0
  0  0  6  6  0  0  5  0  0  0
  0  0  6  0  0  0  0  0  7  7
  0  6  6  0  0  0  7  7  7  7
```

Comment: Array indices [ ] [ ] cannot be used. Only pointers can be used

Comment: @Nzed Arguments of type `int [h][w]` are technically pointer `int (*)[w]`. Note that `[]` is an operator for *a pointer*, not array. `*(copyArray + i * IMAGE_SIZE + j)` is exactly the same as `copyArray[i * IMAGE_SIZE + j]`. However, the second one is easier to read

Comment: Thank You. I made some changes in my statements and it worked. I have to use * specifically as part of my exercise but thanks to give me a clearer idea.